# Abrir alerta quando usuário entrar acessar a tela

Tags: flutter

Eu precisava que assim que o usuario acessasse uma determinada tela do aplicativo abrisse um [alertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html). Porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que isso aconteça. Já tentei fazer abrir com o initState mas ainda assim não abre.

Tenho esse modal, ele funciona se acionado por um botão.

```
Future<void> clienteEndereco() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Complete seu cadastro',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
              )),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Para usar todos os benefícios do Clube Mercosul complete seu cadastro",

                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "Cancelar",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: blueColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                          )),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {


                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "Completar meu cadastro",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: blueColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Já tentei chamar ele por um construtor mas nem assim.

```
  _HomePageState() {
    clienteEndereco();//alerta
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Chama o clienteEndereco() logo após o redirecionamento para a tela que deseja.
Por exemplo, segundo o exemplo da documentação do [flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics).

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
 clienteEndereco()
}
```

Assim no momento que você for redirecionado para o próxima tela, no exemplo "SecondRoute", o conteúdo de clienteEndereco() será exibido!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o *initState()* do *StatefulWidget*, só precisa aguardar a tela ser construída, para ter o acesso correto ao contexto da mesma.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de como pode ser feito:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: YellowBird(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBird({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YellowBirdState createState() => _YellowBirdState();
}

class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
  
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)).then((_) {
      showDialog(
        context: context, 
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("My Super title"),
            content: Text("Hello World"),
          );
        }
      );
    });
  }
                 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: const Color(0xFFFFE306));
  }
}
```

Você pode testar no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter?null_safety=true)

*Obs.: Você também pode utilizar o *LayoutBuilder* ou até mesmo o *FutureBuilder* para ter acesso ao contexto da tela ao tentar exibir o *AlertDialog**